# keep old select value while validation failed in ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, formvalidation.io

In my Laravel project I have an appointment form where patient can choose a doctor after choosing a branch from the dropdown list. I use AJAX for doing the functionality.

Now after any validation failed all the form value restored accept the doctor.

But I want to automatically restored that selected doctor after validation failed.

**html form**

```
<select class="form-control appointment_form_searchField"  id="appointment_branch" name="appointment_branch" style="font-size:.7em;;width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select Branch</option>

    @if($_SESSION['branch'] != null)

      @foreach($_SESSION['branch'] as $data)    
        <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->name }}</option>
      @endforeach

   @endif                              
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="appointment_doctor" name="appointment_doctor" style="font-size:.7em;padding: 0.6500rem .75rem;width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select Doctor</option>
</select>
```

**AJAX**

```
jQuery(".appointment_form_searchField").change(function() {        
    var branch_id = $("#appointment_branch").val();   
    var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
    if(branch_id.trim() != '')
    {                
        jQuery.ajax({    
          url:"{{ url('/filter_doctor') }}",
          type: 'GET',
          data: {_token :token, branch_id : branch_id},
          success:function(msg){    
            $('#appointment_doctor option').remove();
            trHTML = '';
            trHTML += "<option value=''>Select Doctor</option>";
            msg.forEach(function(item){    
              trHTML += "<option value='"+item.id+"'>" + inputem.name + "</option>";
            });    
                $('#appointment_doctor').append(trHTML);
            }
        });
    }              
});
```

**controller**

```
public function filter_doctor(Request $request)
{
    $branch_id = $request->branch_id;

    $query =  DB::table('service_doctors');
    $query->select('doctor_id','inactive_dates_in_this_month');

    if($branch_id != '0')
        $query->where('branch_id','=', $branch_id);

    $result_time = $query->get();
    $array_doctor_id = $result_time->pluck('doctor_id');
    $doctor = Doctor::whereIn('id', $array_doctor_id)->get();
    return $doctor;
}
```

Anybody Help please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide details of your controller file for `url('/filter_doctor')` so we can have a look.

Comment: That code has a couple of flaws. First, you are iterating over a msg properties assuming you received a JSON response, but not json dataType has been set in the request. So, that msg parsing may fail.

Comment: Then looks like you are removing all <options> there even before checking if the ajax  failed or not, assuming you are receiving json.

Comment: If JSON is the response you are receiving, you should return some sort of status flag to determine if the response was succesfull or not. Something saying 'ok' or 'error' in a status field.

Comment: @Deepak...I have updated my code with the `controller`

Comment: @MarkSkayff...Thanks for your suggestions. I will look after those. But FYI, I have received data in `msg` successfully.

Comment: @ArafatRahman how your validation is getting fail in the code?

Comment: @Deepak...the form validation failed while I try to submit the form without feeling any field. And I did that for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5 then you can do something like this.

In your form add missing details appointment_branch and appointment_doctor like below.

The `Request::old()` option load previous posted value in from hence you need to first select old value for `appointment_branch'. Also temporary store`old appointment_doctor`value in`data-oldid` so the script can identify which was the old value submitted by user and can load this select box when document is ready.

```
<select class="form-control appointment_form_searchField"  id="appointment_branch" name="appointment_branch" style="font-size:.7em;;width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select Branch</option>

    @if($_SESSION['branch'] != null)

      @foreach($_SESSION['branch'] as $data)    
        <option value="{{ $data->id }}" {{ Request::old()?(Request::old('appointment_branch')==$data->id?'selected="selected"':''):'' }}>{{ $data->name }}</option>
      @endforeach

   @endif                              
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="appointment_doctor" name="appointment_doctor" style="font-size:.7em;padding: 0.6500rem .75rem;width: 100%;"   data-oldid="{{ Request::old()?Request::old('appointment_doctor'):'' }}">
    <option value="">Select Doctor</option>
</select>
```

And then write your script like below.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if(jQuery("#appointment_doctor").data('oldid')!='' && typeof(jQuery("#appointment_doctor").data('oldid'))!="undefined"){
            jQuery(".appointment_form_searchField").change();
        }
    });



    jQuery(".appointment_form_searchField").change(function() {        
        var branch_id = $("#appointment_branch").val();   
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

        if(branch_id.trim() != '')
        {                
            jQuery.ajax({    
              url:"{{ url('/filter_doctor') }}",
              type: 'GET',
              data: {_token :token, branch_id : branch_id},
              success:function(msg){    
                $('#appointment_doctor option').remove();
                trHTML = '';
                trHTML += "<option value=''>Select Doctor</option>";
                msg.forEach(function(item){    
                  trHTML += "<option value='"+item.id+"'>" + inputem.name + "</option>";
                });    
                    $('#appointment_doctor').append(trHTML);
                }
                if(jQuery("#appointment_doctor").data('oldid')!='' && typeof(jQuery("#appointment_doctor").data('oldid'))!="undefined"){
                    jQuery('#appointment_doctor').val(jQuery("#appointment_doctor").data('oldid')); //select the old doctor id here
                }
            });
        }              
    });

</script>
```